# In R, force x-axis ticks to label each bin in my ggplot (geom_col)

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

**Background**

This could be a duplicate question, but I've gone through several posts and haven't found exactly what I'm looking for. I have a nice `ggplot` I made using `geom_col`:

[image]

It comes from a `df` that looks like this:

[image]

And I made it using this code:

```
ggplot(data = avg_repeats_per_year, aes(x = year, y = ratio)) +
  geom_col()
```

You can see that each number in `ratio` corresponds to a different `year` from 2009 to 2018 (with one `NA` year).

**The Problem**

You can see that each bar corresponds to a year in `year`, but only 3 years are actually labeled on the x-axis of the plot.

How can I get each bar to have a label for its respective year?

**What I've Tried**

I've made attempts of this sort:

```
ggplot(data = avg_repeats_per_year, aes(x = year, y = ratio)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = avg_repeats_per_year$year, labels = avg_repeats_per_year$year)
```

But nothing shows up. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be numeric column, change it to `factor` or `character` and it should work

```
ggplot(data = avg_repeats_per_year, aes(x = factor(year), y = ratio)) +
    geom_col() + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = avg_repeats_per_year$year) + 
    xlab("year")
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
avg_repeats_per_year <- structure(list(year = c(2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, NA), ratio = c(2.28, 2.24, 2.3, 2.45, 
2.32, 2.41, 2.56, 2.52, 2.63, 1.32, 0.56)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Comment: Sorry, just got back to the office. I'll try this now and report back.